# dagger 2.20 support for androidx package structure

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, androidx

Is dagger 2.20 working with the androidx package structure? I'm using Kotlin. I get the error below during build.

```
[kapt] An exception occurred: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.List$2.next(List.java:432)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators.getOnlyElement(Iterators.java:302)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterables.getOnlyElement(Iterables.java:254)
    at dagger.android.processor.AndroidMapKeys.mapKeyValue(AndroidMapKeys.java:75)
    at dagger.android.processor.AndroidMapKeys.lambda$annotationsAndFrameworkTypes$5(AndroidMapKeys.java:56)
    at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$toMap$58(Collectors.java:1321)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$StreamBuilderImpl.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:419)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:270)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1376)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at dagger.android.processor.AndroidMapKeys.annotationsAndFrameworkTypes(AndroidMapKeys.java:56)
    at dagger.android.processor.AndroidMapKeyValidator.annotations(AndroidMapKeyValidator.java:65)
    at
```

Comment: Please, grab the formatted exception *with new-lines* and format it as code (the `{}` button). This is just terrible to read.

Comment: Make sure you followed the advice here if you upgraded from dagger older than 2.19: https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.19

Comment: I have followed everything but I'm still getting the error! Should i be using dagger-android or dagger-android-support or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been completely solved in dagger version 2.21

Answer (score 0):

Add `jetifier-processor` to your project-level dependencies as follows:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta02'
}
```

Comment: doing that gives me this error - The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android/support/v4' that cannot be safely rewritten. Libraries using reflection such as annotation processors need to be updated manually to add support for androidx.